# Corrupted GTK3? Appearance has changed

Tags: gtk3, appearance

Somehow I managed by working in home folder to damage the look of applications. I partially moved my older home folder from another computer where users was named differently. Everything looks this way:

[image]

How could I fix it? Is it GTK3 problem or something else?

Thank you so much for any information.

Comment: I think its just a theme problem

Comment: I tried to change the theme but all themes are affected.

Comment: Check the behavior with an other user account.

Comment: @A.B. Other users are not affected. What shall I do now? :-)

Comment: `mv ~/.config/dconf ~/.config/dconf.bak; mv ~/.config/gtk-3.0 ~/.config/gtk-3.0.bak; mv  ~/.config/gtk-2.0 ~/.config/gtk-2.0.bak`. Log out and login. The problem is in any of this folders.

Comment: Nothing much changed. I also tried to copy the another user .config folder into mine but it didn't helped. I did logged out and login again.

Comment: Have you tried to logout and login again (without rebooting!)? It happens to me in Xubuntu if I login too fast after a reboot. Never found the real cause, i think it's some daemon like d-bus slow to be ready. The second way around is always ok.

Comment: Yes, I did, that was the very first thing I tried. No luck though.

Comment: which desktop are you using?

Comment: I switched a user so it's "fixed" now. Thank you guys for your help, I really do appreaciate your effort!

Comment: Update:  some windows are still affected, e.g. clementine and some others. Weird.